# "sf_frame_dur" in log means?

Tags: android, android-logcat, activity-stack, launchmode

Can anybody tell me actual meaning of following logs:

```
06-02 13:53:50.365  1405  1405 I sf_frame_dur: [com.android.dialer/com.android.dialer.DialtactsActivity,0,0,1,1,2,1,0]
```

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

I only can tell you some information about each value in brackets after checking the .logtags file.

```
# 60100 - 60199 reserved for surfaceflinger
60100 sf_frame_dur (window|3),(dur0|1),(dur1|1),(dur2|1),(dur3|1),(dur4|1),(dur5|1),(dur6|1)
```

All value in parentheses are descriptions of tag sf_frame_dur, "window" in "(window|3)" is description name and "3" means data type which indicates string. Similarly, I think "dur#" means "duration" and its data type is int. So, I deduce that the tag shows the time surfaceflinger spend drawing the window in different duration. Hope others can corret me.